# How to define a feature that will be implemented in next version of the Standard library?

Tags: c++, compatibility

I need functionality that will be added in the next C++ version (C++17). I am using MS Visual Studio, which implements C++11. I expect that in a few years I'll upgrade my compilation tools, so this functionality will be available via the Standard library.

In the meantime, I need to implement it manually. How can I define it so it will be easy to migrate in the future?

Let's take [`std::clamp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) as an example.

- I can implement it with a different name, e.g. `my_clamp`. When I am able to use C++17, I can start using `std::clamp`, and optionally do a global replace of `my_clamp` by `std::clamp`. This looks ugly but probably will generate no surprises.
- I can implement it in my namespace `my::std`, and do `using namespace my`. This way, I can start using the name `std::clamp` today, and not change it later. However, is it dangerous/forbidden?
- I can somehow detect C++ version, and if it's less than 17, stuff `clamp` into `std` namespace. This is UB, but will probably work.

Is there a method without disadvantages?

Is there an accepted/customary way of doing this?

Comment: C++17 is the *current* C++ standard, not the next one.

Comment: Did you consider switching to some *recent* version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or of [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)? They both have better support of C++17

Comment: I like the second solution. Don't see any drawbacks.

Comment: Even a recent version of MSVC should support most of C++17.

Comment: Look also inside [boost](http://boost.org/)

Comment: Number 2 can differ from `std::clamp` whenever ADL is concerned. But if you are always going to qualify it... I'm with n.m.

Comment: If you want *recent* compiler versions, the latest VS2017 is from yesterday. :-)  And of course it includes all the easy-to-implement parts, like `std::clamp`.

Comment: I have no practical way of changing my compiler. Even if I did, there are many people out there who are using old tools.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do in these cases is:
 1. try to use a recent C++ compiler and library that already includes the functions/facilities that I need.
 2. failing that (i.e. I'm forced to stay with an older C++ standard version, let's say C++11, because of old toolchains), find a library that has what I need
 3. better yet, if what I need is already included in a newer C++ standard or a "reference implementation" library already exists, I try to use the reference implementation or a close one, this will reduce future changes in your code.
 4. get familiar with [the boost library](http://www.boost.org/), as there may be a good chance that it already includes what you need, and it may well be the reference implementation for the future C++ standard stuff.
5. failing all the above, for whatever reason, write your own implementation, but try to keep its interface similar to the standard proposal.

For anything not coming from the std:: namespace, use [namespace aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias) to further reduce future changes (when switching to newer toolchain and std:: ).

Note 1: C++17 IS the current C++ standard, the next should be C++20.
Note 2: MS VS2017 (and 2015 to some extent) already includes some or most of the stuff from C++17.

**Edited to include an example of how to use namespace alias**
This example is related to C++ filesystem stuff, it is not (yet) updated to use C++17 , but it's still limited to .
It mainly rely on preprocessor #defines (i.e. HAVE_CXX_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM) to enable/disable the wanted portion. 
I usually use CMake to detect compiler and library features and to define those macros in an automated fashion.

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1900 // Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
#define HAVE_CXX_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM
#endif

#if defined(HAVE_CXX_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM)
// Have Filesystem TS
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace filesystem = std::experimental::filesystem;
using std::error_code;

#elif !defined(NO_BOOST)
// Fall-back to Boost.Filesystem library
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#if (BOOST_VERSION >= 103400)
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#else
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/convenience.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/exception.hpp>
#endif // (BOOST_VERSION >= 103400)
namespace filesystem = boost::filesystem;
using boost::system::error_code;
// Hack to fix differences with C++17 Filesystem TS
#define copy_options copy_option
#define overwrite_existing overwrite_if_exists

#else
#warning Not implemented
// or #include custom stuff
#endif
```

What the above basically does is a fall-through:
1. use  and alias the namespace if available
2. use boost.filesystem (if not explicitly excluded with NO_BOOST)
3. [optional] fallback to a custom implementation or other library if needed.

Disclaimer: this solution may not be perfect, but it's reasonably working for my needs.

Comment: I'd like to see an example for how you want to use namespace aliasing. I could guess, but there is a high chance I'll guess wrong and get nasty UB.

Comment: I think your answer is ok, but it's too bloated. It boils down to "use a separate name space for not-yet-standard stuff, and pick the namespace you use based on c++ version". Which, I believe, is a combination of OPs 2. and 3. IMHO the source of alternative implementation is a secondary problem. The real problem is picking the right one and avoid polluting anything. That being said. All your comments are valid and good advice, but they are addendum.

Comment: @luk32 thank you for your comment. I've also given the fall-through steps I use to select the "right" one, but it's rarely easy to define what is "right" and what is not, especially when you have a codebase that must guarantee to be built with different C++ compilers and std libraries, maybe supporting different versions of the C++ standard and on different platforms... Any recipe you want to share with us?